# Aqua complex scarcity for transition metal ions of second and third row

Tags: coordination-compounds

I've read that for the second and third row of the transition metal ions, almost no [M(OH$_2$)$_6$]$^{2+}$ or [M(OH$_2$)$_6$]$^{3+}$ complexes are known, while they're very common for the first row.

My question is: why is that so? I think it has to do with the fact that elements in the second and third row in oxidation state +II and +III tend to be readily oxidized further, but does somebody have a deeper and clearer explanation?